# WebSocket connection to 'wss://<website>:<port>/ws' failed:

Tags: reactjs, heroku, websocket

I am experiencing a web socket connection error when I have ***not*** used web sockets anywhere in my codebase.

Below is an image of my problem:

[image]

---

***Breakdown***

I have two applications hosted on Heroku, one for the frontend client and one for the backend server. The client is developed with `React` and the server is developed in `Python` / `Flask`. The server is not showing any of these error messages.

This error will periodically show up and I'm not too sure what the root cause is as there's no real way to trace back to the file shown in the image.

---

All the posts I've found relating to this error has code that uses ***web sockets*** in their codebase which is much different from my situation.

I was wondering if anyone else experienced this and found a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using the development server in the production environment. [This](https://medium.com/quick-code/deploying-production-build-of-react-app-to-heroku-2548d8bf6936) shows how to set up a production environment for Heroku.

Cheers.